# Different handlers for jQuery UI Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I make them work together? One tooltip for images and one for inputs. For now I have to choose between them because they won't work together.

```
        // CODE 1
        $(document).tooltip({
            items: ".photo-id img[data-tooltip]" },
            {
                track: true,
                content: function(){
                return $(this).attr("data-tooltip");
            },
        });

        // CODE 2
        $(document).tooltip({
            items: "input[type=text]" },
            {
                content: function(){
                return $(this).val();
            },
        });

<input type="text" value="foo" />

<div class="photo-id">
    <img data-tooltip="big img src" src="small img src" />
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot you attach plugin to elements instead of each one on document?

Comment: I've tried but I don't know why this won't work. (PS. all content is reloaded by ajax)

Comment: combine them and use content function to return data based on element type